# Best alternative for using typeid operator

Tags: c++, compare, operators, typeid

I would like to know which way is the best to compare typeids.  Or is there any difference between the two:

1. `typeid(std::string&) == typeid(std::string{""})`
2. `typeid(std::string) == typeid(std::string{""})`

As output they are both true, but i would like to know if there is something "deeper" to know.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard [reads](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#4) [expr.typeid]:

> When `typeid` is applied to a *type-id*, the result refers to a `std​::​type_­info` object representing the type of the *type-id*. If the type of the *type-id* is a reference to a possibly cv-qualified type, the result of the `typeid` expression refers to a `std​::​type_­info` object representing the cv-unqualified referenced type.

It follows from this quote that both comparisons are equivalent.

Comment: why the const qualifier doesn't matter? for example `typeid(const std::string&) == typeid(std::string{""})` is true

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia, note the words "to a possibly cv-qualified type". "cv" means "constant-volatile". `const std::string&` is a reference to const-qualified `std::string`. Hence, the cv-unqualified referenced type for `const std::string&` is `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent and well document [answer from Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59811672/3723423) tells you that both are equivalent.

But you also asked if there was something deeper to know.  And yes there is:

- When comparing two typeids [`name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) you must be aware that different types can have the same string representation.  So, even if your equality is true, you cannot be sure that it's really the same types on both sides.
- In the opposite direction,  different [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operations for expressions of the same type may return different `type_info` references.  So by comparing the address of the of two typeids, you cannot be sure that it's two different types.

So if you want to use `typeid` to compare the runtime types, you should go for its [`hash_code()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) (which is guaranteed to produce the same value for two equal type and which should give different values for different types, according to a non-normative remark in the standard ). Or even better, just compare the `typeid` themselves with [`==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) as suggested by [Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer) in the comments.

Comment: `hash_code`s can be equal for two non-equal types. You want to use `==` between typeids.

Comment: @Artyer correct.  The standard guarantees equality for equal types but recommends without requiring ("should") a different value for different types.  I've edited.  Thanks for pointing it out :-)